# Angular 2 Lazy Loading : RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am new to Angular 2 and was trying lazy loading. I got error as "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

I tried many other similar questions but nothing worked for me. below is my code for your reference. let me know the issue.

```js
// App Module

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ROUTER_CONFIG } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ROUTER_CONFIG
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// App Routing

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const ROUTER_DATA: Routes = [
    { path:'home', component: AppComponent },
    { path:'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' },
    { path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

export const ROUTER_CONFIG = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTER_DATA);

//App Component

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}


// Lazy module


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';
import { ROUTER_CONFIG } from './lazy.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LazyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [LazyComponent]
})
export class LazyModule { }


// lazy Routing

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';

const ROUTER_DATA: Routes = [
    { path:'', component: LazyComponent }
];

export const ROUTER_CONFIG = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTER_DATA);

// lazy component

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lazy',
  templateUrl: './lazy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lazy.component.css']
})
export class LazyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- App HTML -->

<div [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</div>
<div [routerLink]="['/lazy']">Lazy</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!-- lazy html -->

<p>
  lazy works!
</p>
```

Comment: you don't need to `bootstrap: [LazyComponent]` in LazyModule

Comment: one more query we can lazy load components too or module is mandatory .... how can pass data between lazy components?

Comment: What is the use case? In most of the case I just pass entityId in the route.and Component grab the respective​data from db/sever.. if it is generalized data then you could think of service for data sharing purpose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to configure child routing

**lazy.routing.ts**

<strike>export const ROUTER_CONFIG = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTER_DATA);</strike>

```
export const ROUTER_CONFIG = RouterModule.forChild(ROUTER_DATA);
```

**lazy.module.ts**

```
import { ROUTER_CONFIG } from './lazy.routing';
... 

imports: [
    ROUTER_CONFIG
  ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

Comment: one more query we can lazy load components too or module is mandatory .... how can pass data between lazy components?